# Form Recognizer labeling tool - what is the API version?

Tags: azure, azure-form-recognizer

I have used the Form Recognizer labeling tool to create train and create models. At the time I started I had used the 2.1 preview and the API version was v2.1-preview.3

To use the models created with the labeling tool via the analyze REST api I used the url endpoint and API version as:

> https://{endpoint}/formrecognizer/**v2.1preview3**/custom/models/...

Now the 2.1 GA version of the labeling tool is available.

Is the version of the API used by the from labeling tool fixed based on which version of the labeling tool docker image we run?

- If I use the docker image {mcr.microsoft.com/azure-cognitive-services/custom-form/labeltool:latest-2.1}, the API endpoint will be

  - https://{endpoint}/formrecognizer/**v2.1**/custom/models/...

AND

- If I use the docker image {mcr.microsoft.com/azure-cognitive-services/custom-form/labeltool:latest-preview} then it is the last preview and the API endpoint will be

  - https://{endpoint}/formrecognizer/**v2.1-preview.3**/custom/models/...

Or is there someway I can set explicitly set the API version so I can be sure which API version is being used by the labeling tool?
Is there any settings that I am missing where I can set or at least confirm which version is being used by the tool?

The .fott file has a version property which is set to "2.1.0" in the project created with the preview version and "2.1" with the GA version. Does this property indicate anything?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The project (.fott) file has an optional property "apiVersion", you can set it to "v2.1" or "v2.1-preview.3" based on your needs :)

If this property is not set in the project file, label tool will use the default version which will be the same as tool version.

note: the "version" property in .fott doesn't represent the API version, instead it's just reflect the source control version.

Thanks!